# Trying to create a program that places points along the circumference of a circle, but the points won't distribute evenly. Why? (java)

Tags: java, geometry

I am writing code for a program that draws lines between points on the circumference of a circle. I am setting out points along the circumference, using this equation:

> `x = center + r * cos(angle)`
>
> `y = center + r * sin(angle)`

But for some reason my points won't spread out evenly along the circumference. I can't figure out why.
It ends up looking like this:

[image]

```
    public void setPoints(){
        double circumference = d*Math.PI;
        int x;
        int y;
        int nPoints = 10;  //this is a variable determined by the user
        int space = (int) (circumference/nPoints);
        int start=0;
        System.out.println("space: " + space);
        int r = 20;
        int a = 506;                
        int b = 356;    
        int centerX = a;
        int centerY = b;
        
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter <= nPoints) {
            x = (int) (centerX + r * Math.cos(start));
            y = (int) (centerY + r * Math.sin(start));

            pointArray.add(new Point(x, y));
            System.out.println("---"+counter+"---");

            
            start += space;
            counter++;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What should I replace it with then? I was not quite sure about that myself, but since it places the points along the circumference, I though it was right.

Comment: Still not working :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing:

```
int space = (int) (circumference/nPoints);
int start = 0;
```

With:

```
double space = (2 * Math.PI) / nPoints;
double start = 0;
```

Should do the trick. For clarity, you should rename `space` to `angle` or something.

`2 * Math.PI` is a full angle, expressed in radians. `(2 * Math.PI) / nPoints` is the angle you need to apply between two points.

Comment: For some reason I thought i needed to use the equation for circumference of a circle. Doesn't make sense when I think about it now. But that did the trick, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question correctly, you want to mark a certain number of points along a circumference such that they split your circumference in equal parts. Is that correct? If so, I'd recommend using angles:

```java
public void setPoints(){
    double radius = 2*Math.PI;
    int r = 20;
    int centerX = 506;
    int centerY = 356;
    int nPoints = 10;  //this is a variable determined by the user
    for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
        double currentAngle = i * radius / nPoints;
        x = (int) (centerX + r * Math.cos(currentAngle));
        y = (int) (centerY + r * Math.sin(currentAngle));
        pointArray.add(new Point(x, y));
    }
}
```